# Wiring new ceiling light fitting - old wiring

Tags: wiring, light, fitting

As you can see from the pictures I have an old light fitting I want to replace with the new one which you will see is already wired, but not sure what to do as I haven't seen it like this before. So any help what I should do would be appreciated.

In the old fitting the live and neutral wires coming from the junction box go into the light bulb and the earth was connected before I removed. Do I just snip the wires between old light bulb and junction box and put into new fitting or is this one more tricky than that?

New Light:
[image: New light fitting]

Existing light:
[image: Existing light fitting bulb]

Existing Light:
[image: Existing light fitting]

Comment: _NEVER_ cut wires from a junction box unless there is physical damage that needs to be removed! You want the wires to stick out of the box at leas 3" to facilitate wiring a new device on in the future.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So in order to fit the new light fitting I need to cut the neutral and live wire that are currently connected to the lightbulb fitting then put those (plus the earth) into the new fitting?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the blue and brown from the 2nd pic are the same as the blue and brown in the third pic. If so, unscrew them from that wiring block in the 3rd pic.

Then connect a scrap pieces of blue and brown wire (you could cut some off the old fixture if it's just going to go in the bin) from the screw block in the second pic to the appropriately colored terminals in the first picture.

Remove the mounting bracket in the third picture, then, following the instructions that came with the new light, attach it with whatever screws/brackets/etc. that came with it.

Comment: Thanks so much for this advice - yes you’re right the blue and brown wire in first pic are same as the ones in the second picture. So you said take the blue and brown wire out and using scrap pieces connect to the white block in third picture - so what would be the difference of just cutting the blue and brown wire close to the end where it goes into the lightbulb fitting in second picture then connecting those to the new light fitting (first picture)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the images weren't loading for me when I first saw your question. So, not knowing what your wiring looked like, @Tomnewcombe99, that was just a reflex comment.